# Must I register a script before using wp_enqueue_script() in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using `wp_enqueue_script()` to enqueue a JavaScript file in WordPress:

```
function custom_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), null, true );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_script' );
```

Must I register the script first using `wp_register_script`?

Answer (score 0):

> Scripts that have been pre-registered using `wp_register_script()` do not need to be manually enqueued using `wp_enqueue_script()` if they are **listed as a dependency of another script that is enqueued**. WordPress will automatically include the registered script before it includes the enqueued script that lists the registered script's handle as a dependency

[Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/)

So yes, you'd have to if it doesn't exist previously. Secondly, your script is inside out, you call `add_action()` to *execute* `custom_enqueue_script()`

```
/**
 *
**/
function custom_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 
                       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', 
                       array(), 
                       null, 
                       true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_script' );
```

Comment: So, do I need to register the script even though I've manually enqueued it in my custom_enqueue_script() function? I don't think my script is inside out - rather a typo on my part - I'm just missing a bracket '}' before add_action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register script not previously registered.

[Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)

```
wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

Use as follows:

```
wp_register_script('your-script-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'js/your-script.js', array('jquery'), false, false);

wp_enqueue_script('your-script-name');
```